# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I´m trying to make a Unit test of the methods of my project which contains spring security.
When I run the project it works normally, but when I try to unit test the methods it gives me this error.

```
Description:
Pramenter 0 of constructor in ...config.secutityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframeword.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService in your configuration'
```

This is my SecurityConfig.java code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUT, "/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(DELETE, "/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/category/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/category/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUT, "/category/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(DELETE, "/category/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/product/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/product/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUT, "/product/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(DELETE, "/product/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/shoppingcart/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/shoppingcart/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUT, "/shoppingcart/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(DELETE, "/shoppingcart/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/product/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER");

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
    http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

}
```

This is the test I'm trying to make, it's basically to save a category in the DB.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = CategoryRest.class)
public class CategoryRestTest extends AbstractUnitRestTest {

@MockBean
private CategoryService categoryService;


@Test
public void saveCategory() throws Exception {
    CreateCategoryCmd cmd = new CreateCategoryCmd("Tehnika", "TV, USB", Collections.emptySet());
    String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(cmd);
    Category category = CategoryBuilder.categoryBelaTehnika();

    doReturn(category).when(categoryService).save(any(CreateCategoryCmd.class));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/category/save")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonInString)).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(category.getName()));
}
```

And this is my Userdetails:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);
private final UserDAO userDAO;
private final PayPalAccountDAO payPalAccountDAO;
private final RoleDao roleDao;
private final ShoppingCartDAO shoppingCartDAO;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


@Override
@Transactional
public User save(CreateUserCmd cmd) throws ServiceException {
    User user = UserMapper.INSTANCE.createUserCmdToUser(cmd);
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Role> role = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Role> ro = new HashSet<>();
    roles = roleDao.findAll();
    role.add(roles.get(0));
    ro.addAll(role);
    try {
        user.setRoles(ro);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(cmd.getPassword()));
        user = userDAO.save(user);
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(null, e);
        throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_001, "Saving of user failed!", e);
    }
    return user;
}

@Override
public List<UserResult> findAll() {
    return UserMapper.INSTANCE.listUserToListUserResult(userDAO.findAll());
}

@Override
public UserInfo findById(Long id) {
    return UserMapper.INSTANCE.userToUserInfo(userDAO.findOne(id));
}

@Override
public void addAccount(PayPalAccount payPalAccount, User user) throws ServiceException{
    try{
        payPalAccount.setUserID(user);
        payPalAccountDAO.save(payPalAccount);
    } catch (DAOException e){
        LOGGER.error(null, e);
        throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_001, "creating account failed");
    }
}

@Override
public void addCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart, User user) throws ServiceException {
    try{
        shoppingCart.setUser(user);
        shoppingCart.setStatus(Status.NEW);
        shoppingCart.setPrice(new BigDecimal(0));
        shoppingCartDAO.save(shoppingCart);
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(null, e);
        throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_001, "creating cart failed ");
    }
}

@Override
public void addRole(addRoleCmd cmd) throws ServiceException {
    User user;
    try{
        user = userDAO.findOne(cmd.getId());
        if(user == null){
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_002);
        }
        UserMapper.INSTANCE.addingRoletoUser(user, cmd);
        user.getRoles().addAll(cmd.getRoles().stream()
                .map(v ->{
                    Role rr = roleDao.findOne(v.getId());
                    rr.getUser().add(user);
                    return rr;
                }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        userDAO.merge(user);
    }catch (DAOException e){
        LOGGER.error(null, e);
        throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_001, "failed while adding new role", e);
    }
}


@Override
public void update(UpdateUserCmd cmd) throws ServiceException {
    User user;
    try {
        // check if entity still exists
        user = userDAO.findOne(cmd.getId());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_002);
        }

        UserMapper.INSTANCE.updateUserCmdToUser(user, cmd);
        PayPalAccount palAccount = cmd.getPayPalAccount();
        Set<ShoppingCart> shoppingCarts = cmd.getShoppingCarts();

        for (ShoppingCart cart: shoppingCarts) {
            addCart(cart, user);
        }
        user.setAccount(palAccount);
        addAccount(palAccount, user);
        userDAO.merge(user);
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(null, e);
        throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_001, "Update of user failed!", e);
    }
}


@Override
public void delete(Long id) throws ServiceException {
    User user = userDAO.findOne(id);
    if (user != null) {
        try {
            userDAO.delete(user);
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(null, e);
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_GEN_001, "Delete of user failed!", e);
        }
    } else {
        throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.ERR_CAT_001, "User does not exist!");
    }
}



@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null){
        LOGGER.error("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the database");
    } else{
        LOGGER.info("User found in the DB");
    }
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    });
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: We need to see your test. What sort of tests are you running? Is there a Spring context loaded?

Comment: i will add it now

Comment: Did you try to use the `@WithMockUser` annotation on your test method? : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests

Comment: And where is your UserDetailsService definition?

Comment: @Fabien yes i did use, but nothing still, same error

Comment: @Toerktumlare userdetails is an interface that comes from security.core package

Comment: I know exactly what it is, but where is your implementation of the interface?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I just uploaded

Comment: why did you only update with the `loadUserByUsername` function. I asked for the implementation, that means the ENTIRE class? i did not ask for the single function

Comment: @Toerktumlare well i just put that because that's the only method of the interface to implement. anyways I just uploaded the rest

Comment: If spring cant find your class (as your error suggest) you must underrstand its not the function implementation that is wrong, its the class that is wrong. And spring finds classes by scanning and looking for the annotations at the top. How can i see the annotations you have defined when you just post the function. This is basic troubleshooting, you read the error message and then try to understand why. When someone asks for something, read what they are asking for

Comment: @Toerktumlare I just posted what you asked for.
I´m still learning Spring, go easy on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that if you read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) for `WebMvcTest` it says straight out in the second paragraph:

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans `but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans)`.

Which means it will only load a subsection of the application.

The code provided shows

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = CategoryRest.class)
```

Which will only load the defined controller and the rest defined in the documentation.

The `UserDetailsService` is annotated as a `@Service` which means it will **NOT** be loaded at startup.

If you want to load the application fully you need to use `@SpringBootTest` in conjuction with other annotations for instance `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` or `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient`depending on which client to use.

All of this is properly documentated with easy to read instructions in the [spring boot documentation testing chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-mock-environment).