# Application failed to start - Security Config required a bean of type 'userRepository' that could not be found. Only fails like this on tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security

When I run the SpringBoot REST API it works fine, authentication is implemented properly and everything is successful, however, when I try to run any of my unit tests I am getting the following error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.out.e.config.ApplicationSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.out.e.dao.auth.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.out.e.dao.auth.UserRepository' in your configuration.

I have no idea what to do as it seems nonsensical to me that it would function correctly when running properly but not when being tested?

Security Config:

```
import com.out.e.dao.auth.UserRepository;
import com.out.e.filter.JwtTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(final UserRepository userRepository, final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.jwtTokenFilter = jwtTokenFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + username))
        );
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                (request, response, authException) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            authException.getMessage());
                }
        );
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.cors();
    }
}
```

Token filter:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    public JwtTokenFilter(final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (!hasAuthorisationHeader(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        String accessToken = getAccessToken(request);

        if (!jwtTokenUtil.verifyAccessToken(accessToken)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        setAuthenticationContext(accessToken, request);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void setAuthenticationContext(String accessToken, HttpServletRequest request) {
        UserDetails userDetails = getUserDetails(accessToken);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, null);

        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(String accessToken) {
        User userDetails = new User();
        //Subject was split into userId and email by a comma so split the comma.
        String[] subjects = jwtTokenUtil.getSubject(accessToken).split(",");

        userDetails.setUserID(Long.valueOf(subjects[0]));
        userDetails.setEmail(subjects[1]);

        return userDetails;
    }

    private boolean hasAuthorisationHeader(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String getAccessToken(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        String accessToken = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1].trim();
        System.out.println("Access token: " + accessToken);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

JWT token util:

```
import com.out.e.model.auth.User;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenUtil.class);
    //24Hours
    private static final long EXPIRATION_DURATION = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    @Value("${application.jwt.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    public String generateAccessToken(User user) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(user.getUserID() + "," + user.getEmail())
                .setIssuer("e")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_DURATION))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean verifyAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(accessToken);
            return true;
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JWT Access token is expired.", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JWT Access token is null or empty.", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("JWT Access token is not supported.", e);
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failure occurred while during signature process.", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getSubject(String accessToken) {
        return parseClaims(accessToken).getSubject();
    }

    private Claims parseClaims(String accessToken) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(accessToken)
                .getBody();
    }
}
```

Repositroy:

```
import com.out.e.model.auth.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    /**
     * Finds a user by email.
     * @param email email.
     * @return the user.
     */
    Optional<User> findByEmail(final String email);
}
```

An example test class just in case:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AuthController.class)
public class AuthControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void givenAUserDoesNotExistSignUpSuccessfully() throws Exception {
        SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest("tim@outlook.com", "Password-1", "Tim", "Nook", "London", 3000);
        MsgResponse msgResponse = new MsgResponse("A new user has been successfully registered.");
        doReturn(msgResponse).when(authService).signUpUser(signUpRequest);

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(signUpRequest);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/login")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String response = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals("A new user has been successfully registered.", response);
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Add error full:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationSecurityConfig' defined in file [H:\classes\java\main\com\out\e\config\ApplicationSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.out.e.dao.auth.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: read the docs for @WebMvcTest `Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).` especially the last part... what it does NOT load. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html

Comment: also, you are aware that spring has full JWT support, so why you have written a custom handling on jwt when all that support is included in spring security, i have no idea. Writing custom security solutions is bad practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050028/error-creating-bean-with-name-securityconfig-defined-in-file)

Comment: @Toerktumlare I followed a tutorial. I am unsure what to do now, I had many tests that were all working fine before I implemented this obviously using this annotation. Is there a way to refactor the config class so that it doesn't throw this error? for example I have added the findUserByEmail method to the service class and call that instead which has resolved that but the JwtTokenFilter class is still throwing the error.   Or should I just try to use SpringBootTest
AutoConfigureMockMvc? thanks.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am unsure how my tests would work if I didn't use MvcTest because without it I would need to send bearer token on each request of each test as Spring security would be enabled on for example SpringBootTest / AutoConfigureMockMvc

Comment: You need an `@MockBean` for the `UserRepository` as well. The `@WebMvcTest` will only construct the web related parts of the application including security. Anything else (the services, repositories etc.) you need to mock. You mocked the `UserService` but you also need a mock of the `UserRepository`.

Comment: i dont know how your tests are supposed to work either, im only telling you what your problem is and why it is not working. Tbh i would suggest you dont just google for tutorial and instead read the spring boot documentation chapter on testing, and read the spring security documentation on testing, and when you have read that you'll understand what you can do, and then you write your tests/update your tests.