# Error creating bean with name 'customerSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAuthEntryPoint'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Exception while running JUnit tests

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAuthEntryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cts.customermanager.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cts.customermanager.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 89 more
```

Authentication filter class

```
    package com.cts.customermanager.security;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
    
    
    @Component
    public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailService userService;
        
        @Autowired
        private JwtProvider jwtProvider;
        
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            String token =null, username = null;
            if(StringUtils.hasText(header) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                token = header.substring(7);
                username = jwtProvider.getUserName(token);
            }
            if(username!=null && jwtProvider.validateJWTToken(token)) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(jwtProvider.getUserName(token));
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthToken);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Authentication entry point

```
    package com.cts.customermanager.security;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    
    import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
    import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Component
    public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,authException.getMessage());
        }
    
    }
```

Test class for controller

```
    package com.cts.customermanager.controllerTest;
    
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
    import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.cts.customermanager.service.customerService;
    import com.cts.customermanager.util.Constants;
    
    
    @WebMvcTest
    public class CustomerControllerTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        
        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
        @MockBean
        private CustomerService customerService;
        
        
        @Test
        public void addcustomerTest() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception {
    
            CustomerDto customerDto = getcustomerDto(); //method which returns dto object
            
            Mockito.when(customerService.addcustomer(Mockito.any(customerDto.class))).thenReturn(Constants.customer_ADDED_SUCCESS);
            
            mockMvc.perform(post("/customer")
                    .contentType("application/json").header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer someToken")
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customerDto)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("Success"));
        }
```

Security config class

```
    package com.cts.customermanager.config;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import com.cts.customermanager.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    import com.cts.customermanager.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
    import com.cts.customermanager.security.UserDetailService;
    
    @Component
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class CustomerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthEntryPoint;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailService userDetailService;
    
        @Bean
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
    
        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
        
    }
```

controller class

```
    package com.cts.customermanager.controller;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
    
    import com.cts.customermanager.dto.CustomerDto;
    import com.cts.customermanager.exceptions.CustomerNotFoundException;
    import com.cts.customermanager.service.CustomerService;
    import com.cts.customermanager.service.CustomerServiceImpl;
    
    @RestController
    public class CustomerDbController {
    
        @Autowired
        private CustomerService customerService;
    
        @PostMapping(value = "/customer")
        public ResponseEntity<String> addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto) {
    
                String success = customerService.addCustomer(customerDto);
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(success, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

I am new to spring security implementation. My application works just fine but when I try to test it (JUnit) , I see the exception as mentioned above. Could someone point out what is wrong/missing in the above code which could cause this exception.
Thanks
Note : @ComponentScan on test class did not work

Comment: read the docs using `@WebMvcTest` means spring WILL NOT load in `@Component` annotated classes. This is intentional and you should read the testing section of spring boot and spring security to understand how to test applications that include security. Also, spring already has a fully built in customizable JWTFilter, so why you are writing a custom one makes no sense, at all. You clearly are using annotation you dont fully understand.

Comment: this is addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050028/error-creating-bean-with-name-securityconfig-defined-in-file/73065694#73065694

Answer (score -1):

I guess your Spring bean context is not set up correctly. Try to add the following includeFilter into your @WebMvcTest-annotation.

```
@WebMvcTest( includeFilters = {
  @ComponentScan.Filter( classes = JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint .class )
} )
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerService customerService;

    ....
```